# C - Getting ASCII value instead of the actual number

Tags: c, ascii

I am trying to read from a file that contains zeros or ones in rows like this:
0000100000
0000100000
0000100000
0000100000

I want to store every single number in a 2d array of ints. The issue is that when I try to save a 0 or 1 in the 2d array, I keep getting 48 or 49 instead. My code looks like this:

```
    while (fgets(buffer, INT_MAX, pF) != NULL)
    {   
        for (int x = 0; x < gridW; x++)
        {
            grid[x][y] = buffer[x];
        }
         
        y++;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "rows like this" do you mean it looks exactly like that when you open it in a text editor?

Comment: @slebetman Yes, that is correct

Comment: I notice you mention the word "rows". Files don't have rows. They're just a bunch of bytes. Since you mention rows I presume you mean rows of **text**. On all modern computers text means ASCII (or UTF8 which devolves to ASCII for regular numbers) so those are probably ASCII characters you're looking at.

Comment: Note that **if** you store actual numbers (eg. 32 bit integers) in the file instead of ASCII characters then when you open it in a text editor you will see garbage like those squares you often see in corrupted Word documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` reads a line of text, so each byte contains the character code for the character that was read.

You can get the number the character represents by subtracting the code for the character `'0'` from each character.  That will give you values from 0 to 9.

```
grid[x][y] = buffer[x] - '0';
```

This assumes of course that the string you read in contains only decimal digits.  You'll need to add extra validation if that's not the case.